# Unable to detect touch swipes in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I am using the concept of global hooks (WH_GETMESSAGE) to locate POINTERDOWN and POINTERUP touch events. My plan is to create some touch gestures myself. But I am unable to think of a way to detect swipes. Any idea if I should change my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at WM_GESTURE. It offers the following gesture detection:

- Zoom In/Out - Indicates the distance between the two points.
- Pan - Indicates the distance between the two points.
- Rotate (pivot) - Indicates the angle of rotation.
- Two-finger Tap - Indicates the distance between the two fingers.
- Press and Tap - Indicates the delta between the first finger and the second finger.

You might also want to look at WM_TOUCH, which notifies the window when one or more touch points, such as a finger or pen, touches a touch-sensitive digitizer surface (requires a call to RegisterTouchWindow).

Comment: But I am unable to detect gestures using the same, inside internet explorer, even for WM_TOUCH. Any idea why?